# Extend dataframe with contents of series of arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame `bb` and a pandas Series of numpy arrays, `aa` with the same number of rows.

```
>>> bb
          A         B
0  0.049315  0.362793
1  0.853909  0.590942
2  0.854748  0.247608
3  0.084967  0.293541
4  0.053430  0.922705
5  0.571357  0.404485
6  0.363018  0.070912
7  0.784807  0.641253

>>> aa

0    [0.4648, 0.8575, 0.5008]
1    [0.3056, 0.2737, 0.0137]
2     [0.8038, 0.0858, 0.345]
3    [0.4135, 0.7571, 0.3686]
4    [0.7482, 0.8063, 0.7976]
5    [0.9359, 0.5873, 0.2319]
6     [0.8838, 0.7109, 0.712]
7    [0.6493, 0.1516, 0.5401]
dtype: object
```

I need to add three columns to the DataFrame `bb` containing the elements of `aa`. The desired result is this:

```
          A         B      v0      v1      v2
0  0.049315  0.362793  0.4648  0.8575  0.5008
1  0.853909  0.590942  0.3056  0.2737  0.0137
2  0.854748  0.247608  0.8038  0.0858  0.3450
3  0.084967  0.293541  0.4135  0.7571  0.3686
4  0.053430  0.922705  0.7482  0.8063  0.7976
5  0.571357  0.404485  0.9359  0.5873  0.2319
6  0.363018  0.070912  0.8838  0.7109  0.7120
7  0.784807  0.641253  0.6493  0.1516  0.5401
```

I can realise this with the following code:

```
rows, cols = 8, 3

ixs = ["v" + str(i) for i in range(cols)]
bb[ixs] = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((8, 3)))
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        bb[ixs[j]][i] = aa[i][j]
```

However this is extremely slow on the larger DataFrames that I have. Is there a more idiomatic way to do this in pandas/numpy that works more quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `DataFrame` by constructor, change columns names by [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and add to original by [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) or [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = bb.join(pd.DataFrame(aa.values.tolist()).add_prefix('v'))
```

Or:

```
df = pd.concat([bb, pd.DataFrame(aa.values.tolist()).add_prefix('v')], axis=1)
```

Comment: This seems faster and a compact one!

Comment: @Divakar - Thank you very much!